# MySQL Query equivalent in ActiveRecord?

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I am creating a Rails application.  I wish to aggregate some data based on date / hour of the data's creation.

I can do this easily in SQL but am struggling to figure out the equivalent ActiveRecord query...

The SQL:

```
select date_id, hour, count(*) from data_table GROUP BY date_id, hour;
```

Which returns me rows with date_id, hour, and then the count of records from that given hour slice.

I can't figure this out in ActiveRecord!

I've tried:

```
DataModel.group("date_id, hour").count
```

but that appears to just return counts for the hours in the last date_id...

Comment: possible duplicate of [How does Ruby on Rails handle "Select count(\*) from products group by category"?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3558386/how-does-ruby-on-rails-handle-select-count-from-products-group-by-category)

Comment: Nowhere in that question is there mention of grouping by multiple columns, which was essentially my whole issue...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Someone just answered and deleted the answer...  In any event the answer was correct.

```
DataModel.select("count(*) as count,date_id,hour").group("date_id, hour")
```

I did not realize you could do an ActiveRecord select like this; thank you!